# Creating an Identity Matrix in Prolog

Tags: matrix, prolog, identity

I have to write the predicate `identity/2` which receives a number `n`, and makes an identity matrix `[n x n]`.

Example:

```
identity(3,I).
I = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]];
```

For this one I do not even know how to start. At least an insight on how to build a simple list of `n` elements could provide me a good starting point! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the first thing you need to do is worry about your base case, which I'll just give you:

```
identity(1, [[1]]).
```

Now you need to make it work inductively for the rest.

Personally, I would write some helper predicates, like this to produce a list of zeroes:

```
zeroes(0, []).
zeroes(N, [0|Rest]) :- succ(N0, N), zeroes(N0, Rest).
```

You can also generate lists of arbitrary size using `length/2`:

```
?- length(X, 3).
X = [_G1563, _G1566, _G1569].
```

Other predicates that might be helpful to you: `nth1/3`:

```
?- length(X, 3), nth1(1, X, foo), nth1(3, X, bar).
X = [foo, _G1658, bar].
```

And don't forget you can prepend to a list just by using `[X|Rest]`. :) Good luck!